# setting start date to capture data in google analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I am currently working on google analytics for an application.
The requirement is that i need to set a start date to capture data in google analytics. Is that possible to set the date after which the google analytics starts capturing data.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand what you mean by setting the start date.   The started date would be set in Google analytics when you created the profile thats not something you can change.   You can see when your profile was created by doing the following

If you go though the Mangment api the [profiles.get](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/profiles/get) method returns a [profile resource](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/profiles#resource)

```
{
  "id": string,
  "kind": "analytics#profile",
  "selfLink": string,
  "accountId": string,
  "webPropertyId": string,
  "internalWebPropertyId": string,
  "name": string,
  "currency": string,
  "timezone": string,
  "websiteUrl": string,
  "defaultPage": string,
  "excludeQueryParameters": string,
  "siteSearchQueryParameters": string,
  "stripSiteSearchQueryParameters": boolean,
  "siteSearchCategoryParameters": string,
  "stripSiteSearchCategoryParameters": boolean,
  "type": string,
  "permissions": {
    "effective": [
      string
    ]
  },
  "created": datetime,
  "updated": datetime,
  "eCommerceTracking": boolean,
  "enhancedECommerceTracking": boolean,
  "botFilteringEnabled": boolean,
  "starred": boolean,
  "parentLink": {
    "type": "analytics#webproperty",
    "href": string
  },
  "childLink": {
    "type": "analytics#goals",
    "href": string
  }
}
```

Which contains a createddate.  Which is probably when you created the property and around when it should have started recording data.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to release the tracking code only when data capture is supposed to start.

Instead of doing this in the source code you could implement GA via Google Tag Manager and set a firing schedule for the Google Analytics tags to fire only from a certain date on.

If GTM is not an option you can add a filter that dismisses all requests to the view you plan to use, and on the start date remove the filter (this could be done manually or programmatically, via the Management API).

If your view does not need much setup you can also create an new view on the start day, which will track only from the moment it was created (after that you can delete all existing views).